# feeding custom posts onto template on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am looking to feed a custom post type onto a custom template. I basically want a few sub sections with custom (seperate) post types on the backend panel feed out onto a page, like a news, blog, testimonials kind of thing.

I think have the right idea but I  believe I am going around this wrong. Please forgive me, as I do not normally work on wordpess. I basically want (let's say the news page) to feed all the posts in the custom post type "news". I have a blog page linked to a template that looks like so -

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name:News*/
    ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <ul id="News">
    <?php global $post; query_posts( 'post_type=newst&orderby=ID&order=desc' ); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>

    <div class="fea_del">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_field('post_content',$post->ID); ?></p>
        <a <?php $p=get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?> href="<?php echo $p; ?>"class="entire_job">SEE ENTIRE ARTICLE</a>
    </div>
    </li>
     <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have the [display-posts] plugin in my blog page and just have [display-posts] in the body in hopes it would just feed in all the posts in blog. I've been banging my head against this for a while with no success, I don't work in wordpress much so I'm a bit in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `$args` array to `WP_Query`, try:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'order' => 'desc' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    //rest of you code
endwhile;
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect thank you so much! I just have quick follow up question, regardless thank you so much for your help! I need them to feed out with the title linking to the individual post, and the excerpt. I have the excerpt correct but I cant seem to figuire out   the right phrasing for the title. Heres the code in the array spitting out the entries,  foreach($posts_array as $detail)
        {
   
            echo "<li><a href="">".$detail->post_title."</a><div style='float:left;width:100%;'>".$detail->post_excerpt."</div></li>";
        }
How do i properly link the title and url for post?

Comment: you can use get_permalink()  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( postid ); ?>">...</a> when you are inside the loop use get_premalink() without argument